# concatenate arrays of data in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

I have a set of features in a FOR cycle in MATLAB:

```
 for i = step:indexmax
         Posture(i) = 0;
         MotionLevel(i) = randi(10)/100 ;
         PositionX(i) = 50;
         PositionY(i) = 50;
         PositionZ(i) = 50;
         Features(i) = [Posture(i) MotionLevel(i) PositionX(i) PositionY(i) PositionZ(i)];
  end
```

when I arrive at the row with the definition of the array Features I have the error:

"In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same."

I need to concatenate the features in only one vector ( the output can be a matrix with i rows and 5 colums...)

Comment: With `Features(i)` you index only the i-th element. You need to index the whole i-th row with `Features(i,:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you try to assign an row vector to a single element of `Features`. Simply index the whole row of `Features`

```
Features(i,:) = [Posture(i) MotionLevel(i) ...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure they are all the same size, you probably are mixing rows with columns between the [...].